# CloudFlare CNAME an existing AWS S3 bucket, not named by domain, without using CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare, amazon-route53

We have an S3 bucket used throughout our AWS infrastructure. We currently are using a CloudFront distribution to create an URL for that bucket, then we have a CloudFlare account that maps our custom domain to that CloudFront url. We need to use CloudFlare as we use the CloudFlare image resizing capabilities throughout our infra, but this "double cdn" setup is costing us, as we are charged by CloudFlare + AWS CloudFront.

We would like to cut out CloudFront. The only way I have found to do this is to rename the bucket to the custom domain name (ex: images.oursite.com). However, changing the bucket name would be significant effort, and probably cause quite a few regressions for our infra.

Is there anyway we can setup a CloudFlare cname for our custom bucket, without using a CloudFront distribution, and without changing the bucket name?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can set the origin in CloudFlare to `<bucket-name>.s3.<Region>.amazonaws.com` and S3 will happily serve up the files to CloudFlare regardless of what the domain name is that CloudFlare is ultimately serving. This should be easy to test by creating a separate CNAME record temporarily in CloudFlare.